# Stream a large response from MongoDB using NET 6 AsyncEnumerable?

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-6.0, iasyncenumerable

I was hoping I could use IAsyncEnumerable to stream a response from MongoDB and not have the memory of my API-App eaten up.

I am fetching from MongoDB like this to get an IAsyncEnumerable

```
public async IAsyncEnumerable<Record> GetAllRecords()
{
    var collection = GetCollection<Record>();
    var cursor = await collection.FindAsync(FilterDefinition<Record>.Empty);
    while (await cursor.MoveNextAsync())
    {
        foreach (var current in cursor.Current)
            yield return current;
    }
}
```

And then just returning that IAsyncEnumerable from my Controller.

But alas my application is eating up memory while sending out all the records.
Am I doing this wrong, or are my NET6 AsyncEnumerable hopes to high?

Comment: I think you can solve the problem, instead of iterating through each batch of results using `MoveNextAsync()` and `foreach`, you can directly yield return each document from the cursor, If you can't understand, let me know, and I can explain it more clearly for you

Comment: @Freeman `cursor` is iterating through batches returned from the database. To return individual documents, you do need to iterate over the batch itself.

Comment: @ProgrammingLlama yes you right thnx,each batch contains a set of documents that match the specified filter, by using `MoveNextAsync()` on the cursor, he move to the next batch of documents and the `foreach` loop then iterates through each document within the current batch, and `yield return` returns each document one at a time.

Comment: Exactly, but I do not understand why this builds memory?

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using?

Comment: I’m using NET 6